javascript - Firebase message - onMessageHandler get message_id
Is it possible to get the fcm message_id in the onMessage handler in javascript. I am using server side php to send the message (and in that response of the Send I have the message_id)
Android and Ios seem to have that info in the "RemoteMessage" object
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive
Edit:
Web seems to only have the raw payload https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive am I missing something?
